# Auto growing text area has invalid height after rendering in sapui5

Tags: javascript, textarea, sapui5, autogrow

I has xml view with auto growing sap.m.TextArea

```
<TextArea value="{/abstract}" growing="true" growingMaxLines="100" maxLength="5000" rows="5">
    ...
</TextArea>
```

If I enter big enough text that takes more than 5 rows save it and reload page text area will be rendered with extremely big height. If we try to type something text area will adjust its height to the text.

After small research I found that text area methods `onAfterRendering` and `oninput` use method `_adjustHeight` that takes dom element and uses its property `scrollHeight` to calculate height. But when it is called in `onAfterRendering` there is wrong `scrollHeight`.

I tried to trigger input event but input handler in text area skips events that were triggered by jQuery().trigger().

Maybe someone has ideas how to avoid this or has already faced with this problem?

Comment: we faced a similar issue and fixed it by overrideing the text area overflow update callback. I cant share the code though, so if you provide a jsfiddle or similar we can work on it ;)

Comment: @AshKander, as I understand you wrote your own control that extends TexArea and fix this problem, didn't you?
I had idea to use something like `setTimeout(...) ` but I'm not sure that it will help

Comment: No, we catch the internal resize event in sapui5 and override the behavior of the control. IMHO there is a problem within the text area code, hopefully it will be fixed on day :)

Comment: @AshKander Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just experiencing the same issue (1.44.8) when navigating to a view with a TextArea and new binding. So as a complete hack fix for now, this seems to work during the navigation to the view (basically puts an invalidate after rendering is complete):

```
// Bug fix - invalidate TextAreas
window.setTimeout(function () {
    this.getView().byId("myTextAreaField").invalidate();
}.bind(this), 0);
```